# Browser cache redirecting me to different website

Tags: apache, google-chrome, browser-cache, vhosts

I have two Wordpress websites hosted on two different servers and wish to consolidate these to be hosted on one server.

I've successfully transferred the database and website files over and setup the new virtual host in Apache.

Before switching the DNS over to the new server, I like to confirm it is working by altering my `hosts` file (I'm on Windows) to point to the new server:

`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    example.co.nz`

I can verify this by running `ping example.co.nz` and see that it is correctly pinging the IP address specified in the `hosts` file.

The strange thing, though, is that when I go to `example.co.nz` in my browser, I am redirected and served the other website that was originally on this server; `othersite.co.nz`.

But if I open my Chrome Dev Tools, which has the cache disabled, then I am served the correct site.

Is this just a local caching issue or will other users trying to access the site be affected by this? Is there a way I can verify this, perhaps externally?